# charts_flutter - How to support non-zero Y-Axis values in bar chart with multiple stacks?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bar-chart, flutter-dependencies

I've been trying to use [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) prepared by google team in flutter. I was trying to use stacked bar charts and I was following this [Stacked Bar Charts Demo](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/simple.html). But, there is a tweak I want for my requirements. But, I couldn't figure out how to do it?.

Following is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class WeighAbleStatsScreenV3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeighAbleStatsScreenV3State createState() => _WeighAbleStatsScreenV3State();
}

class _WeighAbleStatsScreenV3State extends State<WeighAbleStatsScreenV3> {
  List<charts.Series> seriesList;

  /// Create series list with multiple series
  static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
    final desktopSalesData = [
      OrdinalSales('2014', 25),
      OrdinalSales('2015', 28),
      OrdinalSales('2016', 26),
      OrdinalSales('2017', 30),
    ];

    final tableSalesData = [
      OrdinalSales('2014', 3),
      OrdinalSales('2015', 3),
      OrdinalSales('2016', 2),
      OrdinalSales('2017', 2),
    ];

    final mobileSalesData = [
      OrdinalSales('2014', 5),
      OrdinalSales('2015', 4),
      OrdinalSales('2016', 4),
      OrdinalSales('2017', 2),
    ];

    return [
      charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Desktop',
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: desktopSalesData,
      ),
      charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Tablet',
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: tableSalesData,
      ),
      charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Mobile',
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: mobileSalesData,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    seriesList = _createSampleData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: 500,
          child: charts.BarChart(
            seriesList,
            animate: true,
            barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Sample ordinal data type.
class OrdinalSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Output :

[image]

Charts are working fine. But, I want Y-axis to be dynamic and non-zero. For example, minimum value for charts data in my case is 25. So, my y-axis values should be 25-35 instead of starting from 0-35.

I do not want zero as starting point for my Y-axis values. But, I couldn't add non-numeric values or values above zero.

Also, It's best if I can add string values to my Y-axis as well?

I've followed documentation thoroughly. But, couldn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When you select the third option, doesn't it give you a link to a tool to download and a command to run?

Comment: I think the bar chart always starts from 0? You can set `measureLowerBoundFn` inside `charts.Series` from a line chart.

Comment: @yellowgray I've already tried with it. But, It always starts with lowerbound 0. upperbound gets extended. But, lower bound alwyas starts with 0.

Comment: @Mahesh P yes. I mean the y-axis lower bound of **Bar Chart**  seems not likely to be changed for this library.

Comment: @yellowgray Can you please tell me how can I achieve my requirement if you know? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample BarChat result that you want? What I mean to say is I haven't seen much of a BarChart **not** start from 0 (Usually the Nonzero Bound  happen on [LineChart](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/nonzero_bound_measure_axis.html), but not on BarChart). Maybe you want a **special BarChart** that may not be supported in the library as far as I know.

Comment: @yellowgray That's exactly what I want as you shown in your linechart URL link but with bar charts. So, is it possible with charts_flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read your question and I've checked out the flutter charts documentation and It seems your requirements are not supported by official chart_flutter package.

As Non-zero Y-axis kind of features are mainly supported in line charts but not in bar charts.

Also, there is one more package [flutter_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_charts) which is not too famous. But, it will solve your use case.

This package has support for the feature of non-zero y-axis as well as non-numeric y-axis values.

Alternatively, you can also create your own bar charts using Stack and FractionallySizedBox for your stacked bar chart requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see a list of instructions when you select the third option:

[image: screenshot]

Follow these instructions, and the command should output a `output.zip` file which you can upload. Not sure what's confusing about the instructions :)